# How to parse multiple JSON objects from a file in Java using URL

Tags: java, json

I have multiple JSON objectsavailable inside a text file and I am trying to get data from each of them to get some data and store it in my database. The following is a sample of the data I have :

```
{"address":"4565 S Wayside Dr","categories":["Other Textile Goods","Textile Manufacturers"],"city":"Houston","country":"US","dateAdded":"2016-11-17T22:36:43Z","dateUpdated":"2017-09-12T14:29:52Z","keys":["us/tx/houston/4565swaysidedr/-1836686262"],"latitude":"29.6981","longitude":"-95.3212","name":"Radium Textiles LLC","phones":["7136901081"],"postalCode":"77087","province":"TX","sourceURLs":["http://www.citysearch.com/profile/607780624/houston_tx/radium_textiles_llc.html"],"id":"AVwdH8-KkufWRAb52ixf"}
{"address":"6104 Donoho St","categories":["Wholesale Textile Brokers","Textile Brokers"],"city":"Houston","country":"US","dateAdded":"2017-03-26T19:08:42Z","dateUpdated":"2017-03-26T19:08:42Z","imageURLs":["http://images1.citysearch.net/assets/guide/images/logo_citysearch_130x25.gif"],"keys":["us/tx/houston/6104donohost/-214331342"],"latitude":"29.677891","longitude":"-95.324173","name":"T A Textiles","phones":["7136452800"],"postalCode":"77033","province":"TX","sourceURLs":["http://www.superpages.com/bp/houston-tx/t-a-textiles-L2170967950.htm","http://houston.citysearch.com/profile/647921770/houston_tx/t_a_textiles.html"],"id":"AVwdbMI6IN2L1WUfvriy"}
{"address":"4544 S Pinemont Dr","categories":["Other Fabricated Textile Product Manufacturers","Textile Manufacturers","Other Textile Goods"],"city":"Houston","country":"US","dateAdded":"2016-11-17T22:33:12Z","dateUpdated":"2017-09-12T14:29:50Z","keys":["us/tx/houston/4544spinemontdr/-1836686262"],"latitude":"29.8369","longitude":"-95.5160","name":"Radium Textiles LLC","neighborhoods":["Fairbanks/ Northwest Crossing , Northwest Houston"],"phones":["7136901390"],"postalCode":"77041","province":"TX","sourceURLs":["http://www.citysearch.com/profile/694636660/houston_tx/radium_textiles_llc.html","http://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/mip/radium-textiles-456243882?lid=456243882"],"websites":["http://api.citygridmedia.com/content/places/v2/click?q=9YKflVKbY9NauPJdMy0B1gS1IhB4xv4EWw0zDoT-UWc_izWF3zs5PKGdfOHubWrvM0QwDCYwbOH2fdLi0dK5xArULcksCCbfR-WWAz9xD1AmGVAQZIom4U3n5R4DuRC8WJCtvJcNItEKoCSfzwapuGnmwGnHDpEGYXGjnN4u8zXqkiimSHFf4_dbqGRbVgNJczcRYGsO7BQjsEDjdlUTJ3CxVQB3K1438yd7WPe-AAAIJEq588kBWNDLbak0Vs-EUxvQmWKBKxWI5ahci9eDn5KNvXpHpqZUL_e0UVacwelpEs92aC0Q2f_N0ZyiviGOHw8dOG3WIXM3rnMIStdm3v06ddF7lICNJl77Z6Y_mtMiylGr2EYGE_lU-dhl6pZnJ92MqQhlZpOjEubWZv1Bd95b8A-INOGKto848V3VdJNGPJwFN_DkdeWGF8YMvDWgew1xs3RSeBeHcBqFzLqQkDbgIllvuxl9VON3HBMwPYjMZ0kqzhi02JRzW0rO_gItNZKuHfHb3rNrWctuJQ2Qvup-kEiLHf5Hya_5KCAgn6uOStAioAXszLKlglJqFMNQE39j6ieFhMg&placement=listing_profile&cs_user=unknown&cs_session=88473fea2af4b100b0e7993b2eafa4bedbe4234c"],"id":"AVwczWsPkufWRAb5zLcG"}
{"address":"7085 Alameda Ave","categories":["Other Textile Goods","Textile Manufacturers","Textile Finishers","Wholesale Textiles"],"city":"El Paso","country":"US","dateAdded":"2017-06-27T05:29:45Z","dateUpdated":"2017-09-06T17:24:47Z","keys":["us/tx/elpaso/7085alamedaave/-266489986"],"latitude":"31.7550","longitude":"-106.3926","name":"Midwest Textile Co","phones":["9158811790"],"postalCode":"79915","province":"TX","sourceURLs":["http://www.citysearch.com/profile/620236204/el_paso_tx/midwest_textile_co.html"],"id":"AVzoBujQLD2H7whiXdiR"}
```

I am trying to parse it as follows:

```
InputStream resourceInputStream =  context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/data/20180427-businesses.txt");
            String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(resourceInputStream, "UTF-8");
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonString );    
            String address = json.getString("address");
```

But since the data is not a single JSON string, this is not working correctly. Also, the data I have is not inside an array and that has made things more difficult for me. I also tried to create a Java Class with similar variables and tried to map the JSON string directly to that class, and it was also not working for me.

```
InputStream resourceInputStream =  context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/data/20180427-businesses.txt");
            String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(resourceInputStream, "UTF-8");
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            BusinessDataImportHB records = mapper.readValue(jsonString, BusinessDataImportHB.class);
```

Where:

```
public class BusinessDataImportHB 
{

    private List<BusinessRecord> records;

    public List<BusinessRecord> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(List<BusinessRecord> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class BusinessRecord {

    private String  address;
    private List<String> categories;
    private String  city;
    private String  country;
    private Date dateAdded;
    private Date dateUpdated;
    private List<String> keys;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String  name;
    private List<String> phones;
    private String postalCode;
    private String province;
    private List<String> websites;
    private String id;
```

I cannot change the format of the data. What is the best approach I could use to parse the data and get individual records?

Comment: What's the issue when you change data as array of json object in text file? I guess that would be easy to parse.

Comment: It looks like you have one object per line. You can read each line and treat it as a json object. To deserialize it you can use Gson.

Comment: As per what @Juan said, or you could correct your text file to contain an JSON Array

Comment: @Scary Wombat, I tried to convert it to an array in the text file by enclosing the data in [ ], but getting the following error:Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

Comment: @Juan, how can I read the data if I have the file URL instead of the file path and there are multiple files, and I am trying to read each line of the data I get from the URLs. Are there any examples I could refer? Also, this might not be each line, the data is a collection of JSON objects

Answer (score 3):

If each JSON Object is in one line you could read the file line by line.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("..."))) {
    stream.forEach(line -> {
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(line);    
        String address = json.getString("address");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your records are on a line-by-line basis and you have a large file, you may want to consider reading and parsing line by line. You can use a try-with-resources block to ensure no memory leaks from unclosed resources.

```
String pathname = "/home/william/test.txt"; // your file
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File(pathname)))) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(sc.nextLine());
        // TODO do something with it
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO
}
```